# How can I sort an array by two criteria?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array I want to echo alphabetized while ignoring the number that starts each string, as such:

```
0 Apple
1 Apple
3 Apple
0 Banana
1 Banana
0 Carrot
//...
```

When I sort, the number is sorted first.  So, I've tried asort, sort_string with no success.

```
$file = file("grades.txt");
asort($file, SORT_STRING);
```

Can I look only at the alphabet characters and ignore numbers? Or can I ignore the first character and sort starting with the second character?  What should I do to get the above result?

It would be great if the numbers could be in order AFTER the arrays are echoed alphabetically, but it is not demanded if too difficult to do.

Comment: You may either split each string into a number and a text and store them in two arrays and then use `array_multisort($arrNum, $arrTxt)`, or write a custom text comparer function and use `usort($arrTxt, "MyComparer")`. See the entire [array sorting functions](http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php) list.

Comment: So where are we with this question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) to remove numbers from beginning of strings, `preg_replace()` accepts third param ( `subject` ) as an array ( the search and replace is performed on every item ).

```
$file = preg_replace( '/^[\d\s]+/', '', file("grades.txt") );

arsort( $file );
```

EDIT:

Use `preg_replace( '/^([\d\s]+)(.+)/', '$2 $1', file("grades.txt") )` to shift the numbers to the end of string.

Comment: 1) `$file` !== `$arr` Seems like a typo 2) How do you then want to sort with the number, when the string is the same, when you remove it?

Comment: With your edited code you change the data from OP. So OP will have different data after sorting.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try php's uasort function.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
    if ($a[2] == $b[2]) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a[2] < $b[2]) ? -1 : 1;
}
uasort($array, 'cmp');
```

Comment: You just compare the third character of each element.

Answer (score 1):

You can swap the position of the alphabetic part and numeric part, and use `strcmp()` to compare the string in `usort()`.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php

```
usort($arr, function($a, $b) {
    $a = $a[2].' '.$a[0];
    $b = $b[2].' '.$b[0];
    return strcmp($a, $b);
});
```

Comment: You just taking the 3rd character into consideration. What would happen with `avocado` and `apple` .. ?

Answer (score 0):

For this you need a custom order function, which you can do with [`uasort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php), e.g.

Simply `explode()` your string by a space and save the number and the string in a variable. Then if string is the same order the elements by the number. Else sort by the string.

```
uasort($arr, function($a, $b){
    list($numberA, $stringA) = explode(" ", $a);
    list($numberB, $stringB) = explode(" ", $b);

    if(strnatcmp($stringA, $stringB) == 0)
        return $numberA < $numberB ? -1 : 1;
    return strnatcmp($stringA, $stringB);    

});
```